# JSF2: ui:include: Component ID must be unique

Tags: java, jsf, facelets, jsf-2

Basic question:

Including a page, that contains a component with component id, multiple times cannot be done. But how can i have a reference to that component iside that included page?

**Example:**

*included.xhtml*

```
....
<h:form id="foo"/>
....
<!-- here i need reference to foo component of this page -->
```

*index.xhtml*

```
....
<ui:include src="included.xhtml" />
<ui:include src="included.xhtml" />
<ui:include src="included.xhtml" />
```

Comment: where do you want to refer it?  
I mean are you trying yo refer it from javascript?

Comment: I'm using primefaces, and i want to use the "update" attribute of an ajax call from a button. That attribute needs the clientId as a value. I'm trying to make this topic not primefaces specific.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With `ui:include` the id will be duplicated.

You can pass a parameter to your included xhtml and prefix your id

```
<ui:include src="included.xhtml">
    <ui:param name="idPrefix" value="myFormIdPrefix"/>
</ui:include>
```

In the included xhtml

```
<h:form id="#{idPrefix}_foo"/>
```

Now it is possible to reference the id as `#{idPrefix}_foo`

Comment: Thanx for your answer! Altough i need extra logic for this as my ui:include list is variable...